# self pointed model in django

Tags: django, list, model, self

class Person(models.Model):

```
name=models.CharField(max_length=30)
....

followers=models.ManyToManyField(Person,blank=True, null=True)
```

above is wrong because Person model could not be recognized. 
I want to has a follower list whose element is also Person.
so How?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
followers=models.ManyToManyField('self', blank=True, null=True)
```

Read also about [`symmetrical`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.symmetrical) arg.

Comment: thanks the model works. but after i PUT a existed item to set some items as its followers, runtime error:

maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
\django\db\models\fields\subclassing.py in inner, line 53

Comment: @whi I am not a magician, I can't help you without seeing the code.

Comment: sorry, i'm using rest framework to crud, http://django-rest-framework.org
it seems its problem, since myself made view does not have the problem.

from djangorestframework.views import ListOrCreateModelView, InstanceModelView
from resources import PersonResource
urlpatterns=patterns('',
    url(r'^$', ListOrCreateModelView.as_view(resource=PersonResource), name='contacts-root'),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', InstanceModelView.as_view(resource=PersonResource)),  
)

Comment: from djangorestframework.resources import ModelResource
from models import Person

class PersonResource(ModelResource):
    model=Person
    fields=('name', 'department', 'title', 'telephone', 'mobile', 'email', \
            'image', 'followers','url')
    ordering=('department',)